# Using an API response to trigger a modal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I'm attempting to use the response from my API (the response being a number ranging from -3 to +3) to trigger a modal. I receive a response from the API and store the number in a state var `setModalVisible` which I thought would cause the modal to appear however it does not. Eventually I would like varying modals to appear dependent upon the number, i.e `if (response < 3) { certainModal } else { }` however I can't get this initial one to render.

Below is a snippet containing the most relevant code:

```
async function makePostRequest (diaryText) {

  let payload = { description: diaryText };

  let response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/', payload);

  let data = response.data.replace(/[^0-9+\/*=\-.\s]+/g, '');


  return data;
}

makePostRequest(diaryText)
   .then(response => {
     this.setState({ setModalVisible: response });
   })
     .catch(error => {
       error.message;
     })

const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
                    return (
                        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                          <Modal
                              animationType="slide"
                              transparent={true}
                              visible={modalVisible}
                              onRequestClose={() => {
                                Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
                                setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                              }}
                          >
                            <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                              <View style={styles.modalView}>
                                <Text style={styles.modalText}>Manderley thinks you are feeling good/okay/bad, is this correct?</Text>
                                <Pressable
                                    style={[styles.YesButton, styles.YesButtonClose]}
                                    onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
                                >
                                  <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Yes</Text>
                                </Pressable>
                                <Pressable
                                    style={[styles.NoButton, styles.NoButtonClose]}
                                    onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
                                >
                                  <Text style={styles.textStyle}>No</Text>
                                </Pressable>
                              </View>
                            </View>
                          </Modal>
                        </View>
                    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea is you just need to check the value after you get the API response.

Let's say you have a function:

```
function checkAPIValue() {
    const apiResponse = functionToCallAPI()
    if (apiResponse.response < 3){
        setModalVisible(true) // Here you change the value of your modalVisible
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just implemented this and I'm getting this error message in the terminal:

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.